# How can I chunk only the sentence has the following pattern <NN>*<PRP>*"run in" <NN> using NLTK in Python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I need only to **chunk** the phrases those have only that pattern, and not chunk another once.
I did it in **Python** using **NLTK library** but does not work

```
import nltk
import re

document="they run in the park"
tokenized = nltk.sent_tokenize(document) 
for i in tokenized:

            words=nltk.word_tokenize(i)
            tagged=nltk.pos_tag(words)

chunkGram=r"""Chank : {<NN>*<PRP>*{'run in'}<DT>*<NN>+} """
chunkParser=nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
chunked=chunkParser.parse(tagged)
print(chunkParser.parse(tagged))
```

---

It did not give the right answer, it retain all document 
result, which means no chunking pattern found!

`>>(S they/PRP run/VBP in/IN the/DT park/NN)`

Comment: Is "play" supposed to be misspelled on line 4?

Comment: i re correct it, sorry

Comment: @mooiamaduck is it now ok, please check

Answer (score 1):

You can use only tags in chunk grammars. [See the ChunkString documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html?highlight=chunkstring#nltk.chunk.regexp.ChunkString).

You can do the following ([taken from here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html) and adjusted to your case).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.chunk.regexp import *

chunk_rule = ChunkRule("<.*>+", "Chunk everything")
chink_rule = ChinkRule("<VB.|IN|\.>", "Chink on verbs/prepositions")
chunk_parser = RegexpChunkParser([chunk_rule, chink_rule], chunk_label='CHUNK')

document = "they run in the park"
words = word_tokenize(document)
tagged = pos_tag(words)

chunked_text = chunk_parser.parse(tagged)
print(chunked_text)
```

The result is:

```
(S (CHUNK they/PRP) run/VBP in/IN (CHUNK the/DT park/NN))
```

**UPDATE**

You can use the [pattern library](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern).

```
>>> from pattern.search import Pattern
>>> from pattern.en import parsetree
>>> 
>>> t = parsetree('Chuck Norris is cooler than Dolph Lundgren.', lemmata=True)
>>> p = Pattern.fromstring('{NP} be * than {NP}')
>>> m = p.match(t)
>>> print m.group(1)
>>> print m.group(2)

[Word(u'Chuck/NNP'), Word(u'Norris/NNP')]
[Word(u'Dolph/NNP'), Word(u'Lundgren/NNP')]
```

Comment: so what can I do, i need all sentences those have that rules + only 'run in' as VB